# How to save the state of delayed posts in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, savestate, android-savedstate

For an Android app I have some content that I want to show with a delay. Therefore I'm using a handler.

```
private lateinit var mHandler: Handler

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    linearLayout.isVisible = false

    mHandler = Handler()
    mHandler.postDelayed({
        linearLayout.isVisible = true 
    }, 1000)
}
```

How can I save this state (for example in case of rotating the app)? And is it better to use `SharedPreferences` or something like this:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

}
```

Comment: It depends. if you just want to retain state for rotation, `savedInstanceState` is fine. but if this state is just one time state and for consecutive app launches you want to retain state, go for shared prefs.

Comment: If you want to 'indefinitely' persist very small data, use shared preferences, else find other ways, which include `onSaveInstance()`

Comment: For _tasks_ (as opposed to _state_), the recommended way to "save" them across rotation is to use a retained fragment: https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html (yes, this is still true six years later). The Android Architecture Components use `ViewModel` for this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel ... These are just retained fragments under the hood!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the newer [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIw96o1tbc4wIVgpOzCh3GYgvBEAAYASAAEgL2mfD_BwE) component to tackle something like this. The `ViewModel` doesn't get destroyed on configuration changes like activities and fragments do, so you can run your `Handler` (or `Timer`) without fear of losing its state.

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val layoutVisibility: MutableLiveData<Boolean> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData().also {
            delayVisibility()
        }
    }

    private fun delayVisibility() {
        Timer().schedule(1000) {
            layoutVisibility.postValue(true)
        }
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var model: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]

        linearLayout.isVisible = false

        model.layoutVisibility.observe(this, Observer<Boolean> { visibility ->
            linearLayout.isVisible = visibility == true
        })
    }
}
```

---

You *could* save the state of the handler—by saving the start time and calculating how much time has elapsed when the activity is recreated—but the `ViewModel` architecture seems more intuitive to me.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var startTime: Long

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        linearLayout.isVisible = false

        var elapsedTime: Long = 0L    
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            startTime = savedInstanceState.getLong(KEY_START_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis())
            elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
        } else {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }

        if (elapsedTime >= 1000) {
            linearLayout.isVisible = true
        } else {
            Handler().postDelayed({
                linearLayout.isVisible = true
            }, 1000 - elapsedTime)
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putLong(KEY_START_TIME, startTime)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val KEY_START_TIME = "start_time"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the `ViewModel` and it worked perfectly fine! Just had to implement these two dependencies to my build.gradle: `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"` and `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"` :)